# Count the number of data points greater than 65.8 sorted by year

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, aggregate

[Data set I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quvcV.png)

I have a data set with a column for years and column with varying integers, I want to calculate the amount of data points where an integer (`MDF` column) is greater than 65.8 per year.
There should be a way to use aggregate but I haven't been able to, I've tried these two lines of code with out any luck:

```
ArKa11 <- filter(ArKaFlowData, year == "2011")
ArKa11 <- filter(ArKa11, MDF >= 65.8)
ArKa11 <- nrow(ArKa11)
```

I get an atomic number output when I try this, which I can't use to calculate further statistics.

```
MeanCMS <- aggregate(ArKaFlowData[, 2], list(ArKaFlowData$year), >= 65.8)
```

This just doesn't work, but I feel like there is a way to use `aggregate` to accomplish this goal more efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're already using the `dplyr` package to filter your data. Why don't you try to `groupby` and `summarize`? This will return a dataframe with a count of records by year.

```
library(dplyr)

ArKaFlowData %>% 
   group_by(year) %>%
   tally()
```

Also, for future posts, please include your dataset in not a screenshot. It makes it easier to reproduce your code and find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum per year regarding your Condition "MDF >=65.8"

```
ArKa11 %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(n_mdf = sum(MDF >= 65.8))
```